# MySQL - slow queries with multiple conditions despite indexing

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a table with stock prices. The schema looks like this:

[image]

In table 'data_1d' there is a unique index ticker_timestamp for ticker_id and timestamp. And a primary index on timestamp_id.

There are ~6.3M rows in 'data_1d'.

This query takes 4+ secs:

```
select * from data_1d where timestamp_id=1387 and open_close>20
```

Explain:

[image]

And it's 20-30 secs if I search for a range of timestamps.

If I search for by only one criteria, timestamp or open_close, it takes 0.1-0.6 secs.

For example:

```
select * from data_1d where timestamp_id=1387
```

OR

```
select * from data_1d where and open_close>20
```

What can I do to improve the performance here?

Thanks.

EDIT: I didn't use statement to create the tables but they should be understandable from the schema. But these are the keys being used in them

**tickers**
primary key: id

**timestamps_1d**
primary key: id
unique index: timestamp

**data_1d**
ticker_id - references tickers.id
timestamp_id - references timestamps_1d.id
unique index (or 2 cols, ticker_id and timestamp_id): ticker_timestamps

Comment: Please add the query plan you get with EXPLAIN

Comment: And proper CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables

Comment: And the different queries you actually tried in different cases

Comment: Added explain and different queries. I didn't use create statements. I added info on the keys being used in each table. The rest should be self- explanatory.

Comment: Read the article https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/12/3-ways-mysql-uses-indexes/ and you will most probably answer your question yourself. The indexes you have are basically useless for the queries on prices.

Comment: The articles point out why having a multi-col key isn't helpful when not searching on the index prefix, which is what I am doing. It doesn't suggest a solution though. 
Plus I have an index on timestamp_id col. Do I need to add another for open_close? That doesn't seem like a good idea.
I'm very surprised that my problem doesn't have a simple solution.

Comment: Create a composite index on `timestamp_id +  open_close` columns - in this order => `CREATE INDEX some_name ON data_1d( timestamp_id , open_close)`.  `timestamp_id` must be first in the index, because you are using equtation operator in the query, `timestamp_id` must be later in the index, since `>` operator is used.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. What if I'm querying on a column that is created on the go. For example, open_close values are basically calculated with open and close values. I could do this on the go (which I'm thinking of doing now), vs having it as a predefined column. In that case would I set indexes on columns 'open' and 'close'?

Answer (score 0):

Do *not* "normalize" continuous values, such as timestamps, floats, dates, etc.

"And it's 20-30 secs if I search for a range of timestamps." -- show us the query.  For that matter, to help you in making the write schema and indexes, let's see samples of *all* the important queries.

"unique index: timestamp" -- Surely you have two different stocks with the same timestamp??

There is at least one ticker that won't fit in `DECIMAL(7,2)`:  NYSE:BRKA.  `INT` won't suffice for an occasional Volume.

`select * from data_1d where and open_close>20` has a syntax error.